# Long string assignment spanning multiple lines without line breaks

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I need to initialize a string with a long string value. The string cannot have any line breaks (it will be word wrapped).

I know I can do this:

```cs
string s = "Here is part of a very long string " +
   "Here is more of it here as well " +
   "and it continues on to this line as well.";
```

But what does this do? Is it using concatenation at run time or is the compiler smart enough to know it's all one string?

Does anyone know how to declare a string like this without run-time concatenation? I was hoping the backslash could escape the new line somehow, but that's not valid. The verbatim identifier (`@""`) doesn't help here because that just makes the line breaks part of the string.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings#string-literals

Comment: @Crowcoder: Thanks. That's what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Crowcoder, the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings#string-literals) does in fact covert this exact question.

> The following example splits a long string literal into smaller strings to improve readability in the source code. The code concatenates the smaller strings to create the long string literal. The parts are concatenated into a single string at compile time. There's no run-time performance cost regardless of the number of strings involved.

Comment: Note that the "readability" comes at the cost of the ability to copy and paste the whole value.  So putting it all on one line of source code is fine too.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Yes, I have--of course--already dealt with this when copying several of these long strings into my code. For me, the work is worth it to get the improved readability.